# iText7 Dynamically Set Field Calculation At Run-time

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

Working with iText7 library version 7.0.2.2 in a c# web application. A PDF document is produced with n-number of dynamically created pages based on the amount of data.

Is there a way to set a field with a calculated formula at run time? So for example, something along the lines of having a subtotal field calculation like

the product of Page1.Lineitem1.qty and Page1.LineItem1.unitprice.

Answer (score 0):

Itext is merely creating the view, the data model feeding it is provided by you.

Furthermore, itext only draws text strings, not numerical types, so it would have to parse those strings back to numbers which can be difficult considering all the ways numbers can be formatted with commas, periods, plus and minus signs, brackets, units,...

And the text pieces you draw with itext are not named.

And itext flushes contents to the output as soon as possible to save memory.

...

So no, itext does not provide support for *"the product of Page1.Lineitem1.qty and Page1.LineItem1.unitprice"* or similar expressions.